# Timeout accessing SOAP API (Magento 1.9.x) after clearing caches

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I've been running into this issue multiple times now—whenever I either,

1. Delete the cache folder for Magento (in my case, `/tmp/magento/var/cache/`);
2. Turn off WSDL caching in Magento (under System > Configuration > Services > Magento Core API > Enable WSDL Cache); and/or,
3. Turn off WSDL caching from the SOAP client's side (via PHP)

I keep hitting a connection timeout error reaching the SOAP server, whether 2, 3 or more minutes.

I've been testing the SOAP client calls with a PHP script from my local server (localhost, Mac with Homebrew—running Nginx/PHP 7.1), while I'm running Magento in a Vagrant instance (Ubuntu, running Apache2 + PHP 7.0—on 33.33.44.10). Currently my test script:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);

// Forwarding the Vagrant/Magento server over 33.33.44.10:
$client = new SoapClient('http://33.33.44.10/api/v2_soap/?wsdl', array(
    'trace' => 1,
    'connection_timeout' => 180
));

// Timeout happens here at the line below:
$sessionId = $client->login('testuser', '123456');

$result = $client->catalogProductCustomOptionList($sessionId, 39);
$resultXml = $client->__getLastResponse(); ?>
```

If I call `http://33.33.44.10/api/v2_soap/?wsdl` directly in my browser, it loads fine—but apparently not in the script.

Any clues?

Comment: Is your site really active? See the test done on this site http://wsdlbrowser.com/ does not load. I believe it is locked for external access.

Comment: Sorry, meant to clarify, 33.33.44.10 is my _local_ Vagrant instance.